# Tower of galois extensions. Prove that $\mathbb Q(2^{1/3})$ is not contained in $K_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, splitting-field, galois-extensions

Prove that if $\mathbb Q=K_0 \subset K_1... \subset 
K_n$ is a sequence of fields such that $K_{i+1}/K_i$ are Galois extensions and $[K_{i+1}:K_i]=3 $ for each $i$, then $\mathbb Q(2^{1/3})$ is not contained in $K_n$. I just want to check if my attempt is correct.

Assume it is true, let $a= 2^{1/3}$ and $f(x)=x^3-2 \in K_{n-1}$. Then as $K_n/K_{n-1}$ is Galois and f has a root in $K_n$, therefore f  splits in $K_n$ ($f(a)=0$). The roots of f are $a, \omega a,\omega^2 a$ where $\omega$ is a third root of unity. Therefore $\omega=e^{i2\pi /3}\in K_n$  and thus $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q[\omega] \subset K_n$. However, $[\mathbb Q[\omega]:\mathbb Q]=2$ so $2$ divides $[K_n: \mathbb Q]=3^n$ (tower law) which is a contradiction.

I didn't use the fact that $K_{i+1}/K_i$ is Galois apart from the case $i=n-1$ so I am not sure if this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor comment: You claim that $f$ splits in $K_n$ because it has a root in $K_n$. This uses the fact that $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, which you do not mention.

Major problem: How do you conclude that $i\in K_n$? This seems to come out of the blue.

As for your edited question; yes, your argument is now fine.

Comment: sorry, I left out the details as I thought they were implied. f is irreducible by Eisenstein and as for $i$, the roots of $f$ are $a, ia, -ia$ so the splitting field is $\mathbb Q[a,ia]=\mathbb Q[a,i]$ and thus $i \in K_n$

Comment: Those are not the roots of $f$; for example if $f(a)=a^3-2=0$ then $$(ia)^3-2=i^3a^3-2=-2i-2\neq0.$$

Comment: I dont know why I kept saying $i$, I m sorry, I meant a third root of unity. The logic is exactly the same though, nothing changes. I corrected the mistake above

Comment: Hi, do you have a reference for the implication
$$
\hbox{$f$ has a root in $K_n$}
\Rightarrow
\hbox{$f$ splits in $K_n$?}
$$
Also is there something to be said for the fact that $G_{K_n/\mathbb{Q}}$ is solvable?
I suspect that this is the reason the hypothesis include the tower of extensions $\mathbb{Q}=K_0\subseteq K_1\subseteq\ldots\subseteq K_n$. Thanks